# Requested labels: ubuntu-latest Job defined at: username/repo/.github/workflows/main.yaml@refs/heads/main Waiting for a runner to pick up this job

Tags: github, cicd

folks!
I'm trying to set up workflows, but the runner doesn't start my job. I've requested `ubuntu-latest` and got a message `Waiting for a runner to pick up this job....` I've canceled jobs and triggered it again several times without success.
Could anyone give me a hint as to what I should do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

That's because ubuntu-latest isn't just deprecated anymore, it's been removed. So any workflow using it can't ever get a runner. Update to a newer version, `ubuntu-22.04` is the current one.